# calculating the investment rate of unbalanced panel data from firm level dataset

Tags: stata

I am doing a project  using firm level dataset (unbalanced panel data). I have around 200,000 firms for 10 years. However, the start and  end of each firm period differ:  some firms start at 1990 and finish at 2000 and others start at 2005  and finish at 2015. I would like to calculate the investment rate using tangible fixed asset (TFA) which is basically (TFA(t)-TFA(t-1))/TFA(t-1) for each firm in Stata. Would you help me on this issue?

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long ID int dec31year double TFA
 1 18992 1638309000
 1 19358 1430424000
 1 19723 2618977000
 1 20088  2.799e+09
 1 20453 3507431000
 1 20819 4219361000
 1 21184 4347613000
 1 21549 3.9619e+09
 1 21914 5100955000
 1 22280 5404411000
 2 19358 1.5479e+10
 2 19723 1.3219e+10
 2 20088 1.3387e+10
 2 20453 1.4867e+10
 2 20819  1.636e+10
 2 21184 1.6547e+10
 2 21549 1.6146e+10
 2 21914 1.4011e+10
 2 22280 1.3141e+10
 2 22645 1.3311e+10
 3 19358  3.201e+09
 3 19723  2.945e+09
 3 20088  2.955e+09
 3 20453  2.630e+09
 3 20819  2.375e+09
 3 21184  2.233e+09
 3 21549  2.166e+09
 3 21914  2.177e+09
 3 22280  2.015e+09
 3 22645  2.122e+09
 4 18992    1425000
 4 19358  395837000
 4 19723  385710000
 4 20088   98745000
 4 20453   20387000
 4 20819    1636000
 4 21184    1499000
 4 21549    1365000
 4 21914    1439000
 4 22280   92866000
 5 18992 4.5909e+10
 5 19358 4.6606e+10
 5 19723 4.5531e+10
 5 20088 4.5645e+10
 5 20453  4.627e+10
 5 20819 4.6155e+10
 5 21184 4.5847e+10
 5 21549 4.5774e+10
 5 21914 4.7443e+10
 5 22280 4.7853e+10
 6 19358  232641000
 6 19723  231892000
 6 20088  190669000
 6 20453  227862000
 6 20819  288878000
 6 21184  302291000
 6 21549  694925000
 6 21914  8.190e+08
 6 22280  7.730e+08
 6 22645  6.480e+08
 7 19358 1288758000
 7 19723 1217425000
 7 20088 1121128000
 7 20453 1033546000
 7 20819  964263000
 7 21184 1020210000
 7 21549 1087107000
 7 21914 1272572000
 7 22280 1310794000
 7 22645 1227395000
 8 19358 2463088000
 8 19723 2630901000
 8 20088 2811077000
 8 20453 3041447000
 8 20819 3257302000
 8 21184 4388377000
 8 21549 4427479000
 8 21914 4741731000
 8 22280 4845817000
 8 22645 5005846000
 9 19083  609320000
 9 19448  619372000
 9 19813  618904000
 9 20178  853070000
 9 20544  838932000
 9 20909  785931000
 9 21274  773765000
 9 21639  760809000
 9 22005  760693000
 9 22370  860146000
10 18992 1617674000
10 19358 1590728000
10 19723 1554051000
10 20088 1445113000
10 20453 1351322000
10 20819 1224924000
10 21184 1081895000
10 21549  133179000
10 21914  114626000
10 22280  110914000
end
format %td dec31year
```

```
. * Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex

. clear

. input long ID int dec31year double TFA

               ID  dec31y~r         TFA
  1. 44 19389  857299000
  2. 44 19754 1230192000
  3. 44 20119 1474218000
  4. 44 20484 1517779000
  5. 44 20850 1542684000
  6. 44 21184 1522782000
  7. 44 21549 1577352000
  8. 44 21914 1642480000
  9. 44 22280 1506011000
 10. 44 22645 1564853000
 11. end

. format %td dec31year
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the data example.

```
. gen year = year(dec31)

. tsset ID year

Panel variable: ID (weakly balanced)
 Time variable: year, 2011 to 2021
         Delta: 1 unit

. gen wanted = D.TFA/L.TFA
(10 missing values generated)

. su wanted

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      wanted |         90    3.778748    29.86207  -.9197528   276.7804
```

Comment: Dear Nick, thank you for the answer. However, I have a problem when I use tsset ID YEAR command which is "repeated time values within panel". I figured out that the reason is that dec31year is a closing date of the firms and usually it is the end of the year: 31decyear but sometimes some firms close their account on 31maryear or 28febyear etc. Therefore, I have repeated time values within the panel. Keeping the closing date as a yearly variable how can I overcome "repeated time values within panel problem". Thank you in advance.

Comment: I shared the second dataex which I hope helps you to visualise. Best,

Comment: Your second data example doesn't show a problem with my suggested approach.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I thought I showed a proper example. I think you can see the problem for ID 44, I have several more like this ID in my dataset. After reading help dataex, I figured out a way to show you the problem. Thank you for the command. Very helpful.

Comment: What to do is up to you and not a programming problem before you decide what makes sense for your project.  For example, you could `drop` any firms that changed their reporting date during the period of record.

Comment: I understand Nick, thank you for the suggestion. However, I don't want to drop the firms since I would like to use this variation for the analysis later (firms could react differently to same shock since they close their accounts on different month of the year.) Again thank you so much, I appreciate a lot the help. I used this formula and I think it is working bysort ID (dec31year): gen grRTFA=(RTFA[_n]-RTFA[_n-1])/(RTFA[_n-1])

Comment: That pays no attention to varying time differences.